# Laravel reset password invalid, can be cause by collation type?

Tags: mysql, laravel, collation

I'm currently using standard laravel Auth class.

Before this I'm using Mysql, and there is no problem encountered.

However, when I'm using sql server, I can't complete reset password. It will display invalid reset password token.
I'm suspect, maybe it is because of the type of collation.

Here is collation generate in Mysql.

```
utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

What is the type collation that can meet with this requirement in Sql server?

Comment: Do such tokens every have non-English letters?

Comment: Hi, im still dont know what the main problem , it just happen when we create table without using artisan migrate only .